# Test Python function raising an Error using Hypothesis

Tags: python, python-hypothesis, property-based-testing

Is there a way to use [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to check if a Python function raises an Error when a particular set of arguments are passed to it? As in, I want the assert to be `True` if the function fails and not make the test execution stop and the function marked as having failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just as you would for a non-Hypothesis test!  For example, you could use `with pytest.raises(...):`, or `try: ... ; except: pass ; else: raise AssertionError("did not raise error")`.

If you mean that it is only expected to fail with an *exact* set of arguments,  this seems like a case for traditional example-based tests; if you mean some arguments and not others I'd write a separate test for each case but you could get away with an `if` statement too.